# Is it possible to directly cast a file list from a query to an observablecollection

Tags: c#, uwp, observablecollection

I am executing a file query and it returns an IReadOnlyList.

```
        public IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> FileList;
        FileList =   await queryResult.GetFilesAsync();
```

This works fine and elsewhere I am executing  foreach loop to load the FileList into an Observable Collection.

It just strikes me that I should be able to load the query result directly into an observable collection like this:

```
        public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<StorageFile> FileList;
        FileList =  (ReadOnlyObservableCollection<StorageFile>) await queryResult.GetFilesAsync();
```

The code compiles, but trips an exception saying that you can't cast a com object into the Observable collection...

Just wondered if anyone had any magic that could fix this? Or do I need to just copy the objects over and live with it?
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object returned by (the Task returned by) `GetFilesAsync()` simply is **not** an `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<StorageFile>`, so you cannot directly cast it, you have to copy the elements.

But you can do that with shorter code if you use the appropriate constructor overload:

```
var observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<StorageFile>((await queryResult.GetFilesAsync()).ToList());
```

[This constructor of `ObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653202(v=vs.110).aspx) takes a `List<T>` as argument and copies the elements.

If you need a `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` it gets a little messier as the [constructor of `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653203(v=vs.110).aspx) takes an `ObservableCollection<T>` as parameter, so you have to do something like this:

```
var rooc = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<StorageFile>(
                new ObservableCollection<StorageFile>(
                  (await queryResult.GetFilesAsync()).ToList()));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help... yes, that works.. although the observable collection doesnt seem to be being observed... but thats a different problem. Thanks again.